# How to update array inside postgresql jsonb field?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with the jsonb field, an example of value:

```
{
    "id": "test",
    "data": [
        {
            "folder1": ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to replace array ["id1", "id2", "id3"] inside this the data to [{"id": "id1", "size": 10}, {"id": "id2", "size": 100}, {"id": "id3", "size": 1000}]:

```
{
    "id": "test",
    "data": [
        {
            "folder1": [
                {"id": "id1", "size": 10}, 
                {"id": "id2", "size": 100}, 
                {"id": "id3", "size": 1000}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If it possible to update it in the single sql construction ot I need to do it with pl/sql?

Comment: Where are 10, 100, and 1000 coming from?

Comment: Having an array of object where each object has a unique identifier is an anti-pattern.  If each object has in identify, use that identify as the key if a higher level object, rather using a higher level array.

Answer (score 0):

If the path of the element to replace is fixed, you can use `jsonb_set()`:

```
jsonb_set(
        mycol,
        '{data,0,folder1}',
         '[{"id": "id1", "size": 10}, {"id": "id2", "size": 100}, {"id": "id3", "size": 1000}]'::jsonb
    )
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bf8df0bac7ec32406e99d405d1bd0673)** - using `jsonb_pretty()` for formating.

Comment: The problem is that path isn't fixed (

Comment: @mystdeim: you should probably have stated that in your question, and provided sample data that demonstrates that (with more than just one value).